# Unbinding keys in cc-mode

Tags: emacs

This is driving me nuts.

I've bound `M-e` to some useful stuff, but `cc-mode` is hogging it. I've tried adding `c-mode-hook`s, `c-mode-common`s and I've tried `eval-after-load` on c-mode, ie

```
(eval-after-load "c-mode"
  '(define-key c-mode-map (kbd "M-e") nil))
```

but whenever I open a C file, `M-e` is still bound to `c-end-of-statement`. How do I disable it and replace it with my own bindings?

Comment: For some reason, I didnt try eval-after-load "cc-mode". That solved it. Disregard please.

Comment: I do think that. Will answer it when I have a minute over

Comment: Generally speaking, it is not a very good idea to rebind standard keys. The [`C-c <letter>`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Conventions.html) bindings are reserved for users.

Comment: Keep worthless stuff such as upcase-region at easy-to-reach spots because of dogma? no thanks

Comment: He did say "generally speaking" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this

```
(define-key c-mode-map [remap c-end-of-statement] 'your-useful-stuff)
```

or

```
(define-key cc-mode-map [remap c-end-of-statement] 'your-useful-stuff)
```